# How to remove Controller and function name from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, codeigniter

I am having a serious issue with one application developed in CI.
Currently my URLs look like this

http://www.example.com/content/index/mission/

I want to remove /content/index/ from URL So, It should look something like this.

http://www.example.com/mission

I have routing and .htaccess method as well. But nothing seems to be working.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css/js/style/system/feature_tab/robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have also tried routing of CI by defining reouters in config/router.php But it was not working :(

Comment: make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled and set `AllowOverride` to `All` in apache configuration.
(Assuming that you have correctly created routes in `routes.php`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific example, you'll want to create a route (in `application/config/routes.php`) that maps

```
$route['mission/']
```

to

```
"content/index/mission"
```

In other words, `$route['mission/'] = "content/index/mission";`

See the [CI documentation regarding URI routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for more info

Comment: Now i removed trailing slash from $route['mission/'] and it is taking me to home page.

Comment: @Salman: Do you have anything relevant you can post from your .htaccess file? `http://www.example.com/content/index/mission/` does NOT give you a 404, correct?

Comment: Yes, It does not give me 404 error. I have edited my question and now it have my .htaccess file as well. Thanks for your quick replies :)

Comment: What happens if you remove your .htaccess (keep the trailing slash in `$route['mission/']`, however) and try `http://www.example.com/index.php/mission` ?

Comment: @SalmanAslam: Do you have any other routing rules defined in `routes.php`? If so, can you post them?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into application/config/routes.php and set your own URL routing rules. (i.e. use something totally different than Controller/Funcction). There should be an array called $route which lets you assign mappings of url => controller/function. Hope this helps.

Check out this guide, its right up you're alley:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html