# Apache rewrite app name from url

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

So what I want to do is to remove the app name from the url, for example:

www.mydomain.com/app_name/index.php => www.mydomain.com/index.php

I want this rule to apply for all my urls:

www.mydomain.com/app_name/name_1 => www.mydomain.com/name_1

and if you know some tutorial for apache web server I would be much obliged

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710411/how-to-remove-part-of-url-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial for mod_rewrite, which is what you're looking to use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Essentially, you need to change your links to look like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/name_1
```

then use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite it to where the actual resources are (in your app directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app_name
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_name/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried the code, but it still doesn't do the specific action I want to accomplish. I'll look through the tutorial and hopefully find something useful.