# .htaccess 301 redirect, remove segment from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to do redirect in .htaccess from:

**mysite.com/directory/page/***

to:

**mysite.com/page/***

Remove "**directory**" from URL.

Help please, i can't find rule for .htaccess for this.

Comment: Take a look at : [How to remove part of URl with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7710411/3924920)

Comment: You have to try something and then get help if that doesn't work.

Comment: We want to see what you have tried yourself in order to redirect the url. Please Post your code.