# Laravel redirects to new url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I want to redirect my old URL to a new URL in Laravel
Example: `domain.com/path/any-page to domain.com/any-page`

What will be the better option I can use `.htaccess` or define every route manually to redirect.

Comment: if you're using htaccess to update `path` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710411/how-to-remove-part-of-url-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect using controller, or middleware you can use `redirect('DOMAIN_TO_REDIRECT')`.

now when you want to use use .htaccess just add this line into your htaccess.
`Redirect 301 /your_route https://example.net/another_route`