# How to remove Controller and method name from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

Currently my URLs look like this

http://www.domain12.co.un/register/user/A123

I want to remove /register/user/ from URL So, It should look something like this.

http://www.domain12.co.un/A123

Parameter A123 is not constant in above URL, It may change B123, G123, 3FG567... etc.

I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603845/how-to-remove-controller-and-function-name-from-url-in-codeigniter) but getting 404 error. I have added below code in my routes.php but it's not redirecting to other page.

```html
 $route['(:any)'] = "register/user/$1";
```

Comment: you remove index.php in config.php ??

Comment: Already removed , but not working . here its $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: your method pass any  argument  in  controller ???

Comment: @HothiJimit Yes

Comment: default set null like   function demo($arg=null)

Comment: @HothiJimit, Yes it is there, but nothing works

Comment: check .htaccess i think that problem

Answer (score 1):

Do one more thing..

Create .htaccess file and paste the below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

and save this .htaccess file in your root folder and then try

Comment: Added code in .htaccess file. No luck.  I have login form in above url and once I logged It is not redirecting to secure(dashboard) page. but URL is changed like this www.domain12.co.un/dashboard but here it showing my login page design

Comment: All the pages(about Us, Terms and Condition.. etc) showing the same design

Comment: Try with this code : $route['user/(:any)'] = 'register/user/$1';

Comment: Getting 404 page errror