# how to trim url with php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to remove the mark on the picture below? this url to create blog details. I use this php codeigniter language

here's the picture:

[image]

Comment: You may wanna check codeigniter routing with regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Controller and function name from URL in CodeIgnitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603845/how-to-remove-controller-and-function-name-from-url-in-codeignitor)

Comment: You can rename your routes on here config/routes.php https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

If you supposed to remove the string from URL, this may help you.

- Make the URL as an array by parsing it with `parse_url()`.
- Extract the portion of your string and then decompose it with `parse_str()`.
- Remove the parameter with the use of `unset`.
- Now build the your URL with `http_build_query()`.

This will give you the URL which you supposed to do.

***Other way:***

If you want to go with that URL by optimizing it, use `routes` functionality of CodeIgniter. Check this below.

**Path:**  `application/config/routes.php/`

```
$route['your_url_string'] = 'blog/detail';
```

Answer (score 0):

add like this

**In application/config/ruotes.php**

```
$route['(.*)'] = 'YourController/YourMethod'; // example 'blog/detail'
```

**In Your Controller** - I guess `Blog` is a controller and `detail` is the method

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function detail(){
        $id = $this->uri->segment(1); // return 8
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(2); // return 77-anniversary
    }
}
```

**In View**

```
<a href="<?=base_url('8/77-anniversary');?>">Title</a>
```